How to hightlight javascript variable that is not defined or notify about any exists?
Maybe there is some plugin that includes this feature?
Also some plugin for jumping to typescript definitions, with useful typescript interaction features?

Sounds like you want to use one of the LSP plugins. I use https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim

Welcome to Vim! Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

As suggested by @Heptite this is typically provided by an LSP server.
A popular LSP bridge for Vim is coc.nvim.
A popular LSP server for javascript is tsserver.
After installing coc.nvim you can run the following command to install the tsserver and link it with coc.nvim
:CocInstall coc-tsserver

The tsserver:

Let you jump to the definition of function (typically with the gd key command if you follow the coc.nvim configuration proposal
Identify the variables that are not used

Remark: the tsserver doesn't seems to identify the variables that are not declared.
